# How can i use “Run Keyword If Any Critical Tests Failed” in robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

I want to stop the desktop application from running once the application crashes.
How can i use this condition in all scripts with RIDE - robot framework ?

```
Run Keyword If Any Critical Tests Failed
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. You use it like any other keyword, except that the documentation states you can only use it in a suite teardown. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]You can only use this Keyword in Suite teardown . For Test teardown you can use "Run Keyword If Test Failed" .